# show progress dialog in AsyncTask class in retrofit

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit2, progressdialog

I'm developing and android app.
I have to call API and get the result.So i use retrofit library and call the API.
All code and working and get result fine.

i want to get data while showing and update progress dialog and after finish  progress dialog dismiss.

i try it.but i can only show it and dismiss progress dialog in the onResponse class.

can't call AsyncTask class onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate method.

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public  ClientInfo(Context ct){
    WeakReference<Context> contextRef = new WeakReference<>(ct);
    progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(contextRef.get());
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String token = strings[0];
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.Api)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    GetClientApi getClientApi = retrofit.create(GetClientApi.class);
    Call<ClientApiInfo> clientApiInfoCall =  getClientApi.getClientApiInfo(token);

    clientApiInfoCall.enqueue(new Callback<ClientApiInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ClientApiInfo> call, @NonNull Response<ClientApiInfo> response) {

            if(response.code() == 200){              
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            else if (response.code() == 404) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ClientApiInfo> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Start");
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    super.onPostExecute(s);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    progressDialog.setMessage(values[0]);
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

i need ruining doInbackground method while update progress dialog and after that finished get data show massage and dismiss.

Thank you.

Comment: You do not need an `AsyncTask` . RetroFIt `#enqueue()`  calls are already on worker thread . Just remove all this `AsyncTask` and call it directly from main thread .

Comment: Remove AsyncTask and call it directly from main thread also check below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301818/retrofit-2-how-to-show-progress-bar-on-receiving-json-response

Comment: @ADM thanks for your reply.it's nice tips thanks.so why we use AsyncTask class.i saw tot of tutorial use.is it old method?

Comment: @RahulArora thank for your reply. it's valuable tips for me .